# Flickr-like script: Alter element height to make column width match end-to-end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does such a script exist?

Masonry and flexbox do not make columns match end to end, like Flickr does; and obviously so, because neither resize height.

I want to be able to take elements of any (relative) width, and have a script resize their height like Flickr .

---

Basically, take a container with 6 elements. Imagine they exist as 2 columns with 3 rows.

Now, if element #2 is a few pixels more narrow than the other 5, the top column will end a few pixels before the bottom column does. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D Where shall I ask?